# CV quote alignment

Tags: moderncv, quoting, alignment

I just want my quote from casual modern CV to be justify instead of centered.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{first}{last}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\quote{\lipsum[2]}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can load the `ragged2e` package which provides a `\justifying` macro, and then use

```
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape\justifying}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{first}{last}

\usepackage{ragged2e} % provides \justifying
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape\justifying}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\quote{\lipsum[2]}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Torbjørn T., I have a question related with this answer that maybe you can solve here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498211/192035 . Many thanks!