# Use real text instead of lipsum in moderncv quote alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv, lipsum

I'm trying to justify the initial quote in `moderncv` package. And the following answer seems to provide a proper solution:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440444/192035

However, when I try to replace the text generated with `lipsum` with actual text, the justify aligment is lost. Trying to understand the reason, I found that [`lipsum` doesn't add plain text](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/505/192035), but it also adds some extra formatting. However, I not able to fully understand the problem and how to solve it.

This is the solution using `lipsum`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{first}{last}

\usepackage{ragged2e} % provides \justifying
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape\justifying}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\quote{\lipsum[2]}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here the problem after replacing `lipsum`generated text with actual text:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{first}{last}

\usepackage{ragged2e} % provides \justifying
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape\justifying}

\quote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dicant civibus ius an. Mel te minim urbanitas forensibus, ad vel probatus eloquentiam, an per accusam noluisse. Cum brute mollis conceptam ne, vel inani theophrastus at. Discere mediocrem intellegebat vis at, atqui error no sit.
Ea sit ferri fierent argumentum, stet philosophia eu quo. Vix tantas eligendi perpetua ne, tale mazim liber vel ne, eam ad suscipit gloriatur. Nec ut sonet nonumes democritum, inani labore admodum eu est. Mea ea cetero luptatum posidonium, in probo exerci eam.}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think \lipsum adds a paragraph break at the end, try ending your quote text with `\par`.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, it was the only thing I tried before posting the question, but I didn't describe it in the question because I don't fully understant what `\par` does. Anyway, it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I get centering also with `\lipsum`, with a recent version, because `lipsum` no longer adds `\par` at the end of its paragraphs, but at the beginning.

The problem is with `\makecvtitle` typesets the text stored in `\@quote` inside an unnecessary group. Unfortunately, doing

```latex
\quote{stuff\par}
```

isn't going to work, because `\quote` is not a “long” command. What happens is that `\makecvtitle` does `\makecvhead`, which in turn does

```latex
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}
  {}
  {{\null \hfill \begin {minipage}{\quotewidth }\centering \quotestyle {\@quote }\end{minipage}...
```

and `\quotestyle` is defined as

```latex
{\quotefont \textcolor {color1}{#1}}
```

with an additional brace level. Thus `\justifying` is undone before `minipage` ends, and you get the default `\centering`.

Workaround: redefine `\quotestyle` to suppress the additional braces.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{first}{last}

\usepackage{ragged2e} % provides \justifying
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape\justifying}
\renewcommand{\quotestyle}[1]{\quotefont\color{color1}#1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\quote{\lipsum[2]}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\quote{stuff\endgraf}`  works too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, but I wouldn't advertise it. It's better to fix the wrong definition of `\quotestyle`.

Answer (score 4):

Directly adding `\par` seems not to work, but outsourcing the text in a new command seems to do the trick:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{first}{last}

\usepackage{ragged2e} % provides \justifying
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape\justifying}

\newcommand{\quotetext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dicant civibus ius an. Mel te minim urbanitas forensibus, ad vel probatus eloquentiam, an per accusam noluisse. Cum brute mollis conceptam ne, vel inani theophrastus at. Discere mediocrem intellegebat vis at, atqui error no sit.
Ea sit ferri fierent argumentum, stet philosophia eu quo. Vix tantas eligendi perpetua ne, tale mazim liber vel ne, eam ad suscipit gloriatur. Nec ut sonet nonumes democritum, inani labore admodum eu est. Mea ea cetero luptatum posidonium, in probo exerci eam.\par}

\quote{\quotetext}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response! It works as expected. However, let me accept @egreg's response since he provides a more detailed explanation of the problem and why the solution works.